# Apache MINA networking - How to get data from org.apache.mina.core.service.IoHandlerAdapter messageRecieved(IoSession, Object)

Tags: apache-mina

```
public void messageReceived(IoSession session, Object message) throws Exception 
{
    // do something
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to get data from the Object?

Answer (score 2):

It's really quite simple, just cast the message into an IoBuffer and pull out the bytes.

```
// cast message to io buffer
IoBuffer data = (IoBuffer) message;
// create a byte array to hold the bytes
byte[] buf = new byte[data.limit()];
// pull the bytes out
data.get(buf);
// look at the message as a string
System.out.println("Message: " + new String(buf));
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast message to the object type you used in the client's session.write.